# Rails 5 ReferenceError: function is not defined

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

I'm trying (all morning now :-S) to load a js function on onChange to fill in some fields in a form.
I've already searched for solutions for this, which made me add jquery-turbolinks and even try and remove turbolinks. This didn't work.

Why is it that the function is not recognized ?

> ReferenceError: update_sub_process_fields is not defined

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require bootstrap-datepicker/core
//= require bootstrap-datepicker/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.pt.js
//= require_tree .
```

sub_processes.coffee

```
ready = ->

update_sub_process_fields = (sub_process_type_id) ->
  jQuery.ajax
    url: '/sub_processes/update_fields'
    type: 'GET'
    data: 'sub_process_type_id': sub_process_type_id
    dataType: 'html'
    success: (data) ->
      jQuery('#sub_process_fields').html data
      return
  return

$(document).ready(ready)
$(document).on('page:load', ready)
```

_form.erb.html

```
 <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :sub_process_type %>
   <%= f.select(:sub_process_type_id, options_for_select(SubProcessType.all.map {|s| [s.name, s.id]},sub_process.sub_process_type_id),{prompt: "Select Sub Process...", include_blank:true}, onChange: "update_sub_process_fields(this.value)") %>
  </div>


  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :codenr %>
    <%= f.text_field :codenr %>
  </div>

<div id = "sub_process_fields">
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_field :description %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 1. Is the indentation correct in you coffeescript sample? I think `update_sub_process_fields` should be indented to be inside your ready function?
2. Try using `window.update_sub_process_fields = ...` instead of `update_sub_process_fields = ...`. If it works, I'll add an answer to explain why

Comment: Thank you very much, adding `window.` fixed it.
indentation didn't do anything (besides increasing readability).

Do please explain.

Comment: " indentation didn't do anything (besides increasing readability)" is not right, indentation defines the structure of CoffeeScript. What you have in your question is an empty `ready` function.

Comment: @muistooshort, in this specific scenario, adding window and leaving indentation as originally was also worked.

Comment: @MrWater, actually @muistooshort is right. Your compiled JS for ready looks like this: `ready = function() {};`, meaning `window.update_sub_process_fields` is defined before your ready event - this is fine as it doesn't need jQUery or the DOM until it is triggered via the event. But I would assume that it should be inside your `ready` function, as otherwise both `ready` and the `$(document)...` statements do nothing.

Comment: plus one for the explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution

As per my comment, you need to expose your function via the global `window` object.

So replace:

```
update_sub_process_fields = (sub_process_type_id) ->
```

with:

```
window.update_sub_process_fields = (sub_process_type_id) ->
```

## Explanation

Coffeescript doesn't make local variables globally accessible. In JS you could write:

```
var a = 1;
b = 2;
```

Here `a` would be local to the current context, while `b` is a global variable.

As there is no `var` keyword in Coffeescript, it makes every variable local (to avoid polluting the global namespace and causing errors ). To expose it you need to use a system like commonjs for importing/exporting across files **or** you can attach it to a global object. In a browser this is `window`, while in a server side nodejs app it would be `global`.

You could get around it by attaching the `onChange` event via a [delegated listener](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) in your coffeescript.

eg:

```
document.on 'change', '.sub_process_type', update_sub_process_fields
```

where `.sub_process_type` is a class on the select box you want to listen for changes on.

---

## Edit

To get the value via the event listener, you will have to use the `event` object [which is passed to event listeners by default](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/).

```
update_sub_process_fields = (event) ->
  sub_process_type_id = event.target.value
  jQuery.ajax
    url: '/sub_processes/update_fields'
    type: 'GET'
    data: 
      sub_process_type_id: sub_process_type_id
    dataType: 'html'
    success: (data) ->
      jQuery('#sub_process_fields').html data
      return
  return
```

---

Comment: using  `document.on 'change', '.sub_process_type', update_sub_process_fields`  wouldn't get me the current selected value, or would it ?

Comment: @MrWater See the edit above. You will need to grab the selected value from the event object which includes a reference to the select element